# large memory: wakeup slower than boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, ssd, hibernate

I've upgraded my Windows 7 machine to 24GB.

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/209541/windows-7-pagefile-size-with-large-ram-and-ssd), I found out that 24GB of my precious C: SSD were taken for swap file. To solve this, I moved the swap file to my 2TB non SSD E: drive.

So, I though I've got everything under control. However, I find out that resuming after sleep is much slower than booting up the system. I think this is because on wakeup the system has to read 24GB of RAM from the hard disk (non SSD), while on boot-up the system has to read much a much smaller amout and from an SSD, to boot (pun intended). This is bad because a system wakes-up much more frequently that it boots-up.

Any ideas how to solve this large-memory/SSD driver gotcha?

Comment: Personally, if I'm booting off SSD, I don't see the point of using hibernation at all due to the speed issues you've experienced.

Comment: Also, I might point out that the page file and the hibernate file are not the same thing.

Comment: Can you please clarify if this is about sleep or about hibernation? Because those two are quite different aspects and I'm unsure about which of the two you are talking. Sleep should be lightning fast, hibernation will indeed be slower because your slower HDD is involved. Heck, hibernating 24 GB to a HDD is indeed slow. So I would recommend, either go for sleep or get used to booting...