# Windows 7 and Paging

Tags: windows-7, memory, pagefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need for page file with 12 GB RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/229387/need-for-page-file-with-12-gb-ram)

I've got a system with 24 GB of RAM and with Windows 7 installed on a 120 GB SSD volume.  The problem is that with default settings Windows is allocating a pagefile 24 GB in size and is using an additional 19 GB for the hibernation file (`hiberfil.sys`).  This is a little bit ridiculous, as nearly half of the available space on the SSD is now being claimed by system resources (I've also got a pair of 2 TB traditional HDD's in RAID-1 for data storage, but obviously that volume is not for things that are supposed to load/access quickly like system files).  It's probably subjecting my SSD to unnecessary write-cycles, as well.

In any case, I was wondering if there are any negative repercussions to disabling the pagefile completely, given the large amount of installed RAM?  I know for some reason turning off paging was strongly discouraged under Windows XP, but does that still apply, even if you have 24 GB of RAM?

Comment: yes, a few programs will fail , sometimes with rediculously stupid errors :-) EX: "To much memory" ???  I have hated paging from day1 , I actually prefered the old method of Fail :-) when not enough actual.  But generally I have to keep a small paging file so I dont have to spend hours figuring out why a program failed. a tiny one will do, a 512M has always been ok for everything.