# Is it okay if I lower my pagefile size in Windows 10 as I've got plenty of hardware RAM to deal with it?

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, pagefile

The pagefile is currently automatically allocated through Windows 10 itself. It seems that it has allocated `5888 MB` of disk space.

My system has `32 GB` of RAM available and my intention was to lower the pagefile in size so that more of the faster RAM would be used instead of the virtual one. Is there any real merit in doing so? [A question like this one was asked way back in 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/209541/windows-pagefile-size-with-large-ram-and-ssd). But I'm still wondering if the answer to that still holds true in 2021

Thank you!

Comment: The traditional Pagefile size was ~1.5 * RAM size, which would be 48,000 MB. Since Windows has set it to far smaller, I *wouldn't* decrease it. However, to avoid disk fragmentation, you might set it to have minimum and maximum size the same.

Comment: Disk fragmentation is of no import on an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be worth setting fixed sizes, back in the days everything was on spinny rust & people didn't have much RAM to play with.
Tricks like setting a tiny pagefile on the boot drive & significantly more on a separate physical disk were great back in WinXP days.

With a lot of RAM & an SSD, there's probably little to be gained by not leaving it as System Managed these days.